# Method to solve given partial differential equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let $u = u(x,y,z)$ satisfies

$$ \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial z^{2}} = f(x,y,z) $$

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,w,z) = f_{1}(x,z) $$
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,-w,z) = f_{2}(x,z) $$
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}(x,y,h) = f_{3}(x,y) $$
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}(x,y,-h) = f_{4}(x,y) $$
where $h,w$ are constants.
Can anyone suggest to me a method to solve the above partial differential equation with given boundary conditions? I am interested to find analytical solution but if no analytical solution can be drawn then I will apply some numerical methods.

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to be a Laplacian without any $x$ derivatives? And is the inhomogeneity $f$ related top the $f_{i}$ in the boundary conditions? I suppose the usual approach would be to apply separation of variables to each of the problems $\{f_{1} \ne 0, f_{2}, f_{3}, f_{4} = 0\}$, $\{f_{1} = 0, f_{2} \ne 0, f_{3}, f_{4} = 0\}$, $\{f_{1}, f_{2} = 0, f_{3} \ne 0, f_{4} = 0\}$, $\{f_{1}, f_{2}, f_{3} = 0, f_{4} \ne 0\}$ to yield solutions $u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}, u_{4}$, then the solution $u$ is a linear combination of the $u_{i}$.

Comment: Yeah, there is no $x$ derivative, and $f, f_{i}$ are not related.